# Que evento se usa para minimizar y maximizar una aplicacion en ionic 4?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

Estoy desarrollando una aplicacion en ionic pero no encuentro los eventos cuando se presiona en el celular el boton home y la aplicación se minimiza o se manda a segundo plano, y al volver abrir la aplicación refresque la pagina y no cargue los datos que están en cache, lo que quiero que refrescar la vista y todo los comeponentes que trae datos de la base de datos por medios de una API, pero no encuentro resultados con respecto a refrescar la pagina cuando esta minimizado. Intente usar los eventos ionViewWillEnter,ionViewDidEnter,ionViewWillLeave y ionViewDidLeave pero no me dio resultados a lo que quiero hacer. Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El evento que tienes que escuchar cuando la aplicación entra en segundo plano es método `pause` de la clase `platform`.
https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/platform#pause

Para escuchar cuando la app vuelve a primer plano el metodo que tienes que escuchar es el `resume` tambien de la clase `platform`.
https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/platform#resume

Ejemplo

```
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
 this.platform.pause.subscribe(() => {        
     console.log('****UserdashboardPage PAUSED****');
 });  
 this.platform.resume.subscribe(() => {      
     console.log('****UserdashboardPage RESUMED****');
 });
});
```

Comment: Gracias, esto era lo que buscaba